# How can I access the js file referenced in a script tag in a WordPress template?

Tags: php, linux, wordpress

I have a WordPress template which works fine, but in the bottom of the template there is a script tag that loads the js function:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://essenceraw.com/_static/??-eJx9zEEKgzAQheELGYcaqt2UniVMokTMTMhMyPUVW6grdw9+3teyQSYNpJC3ukQSaMzIKYWCAZxIUIFVwCFyJY20XGafIvWrdO1WMbmwr6jGec9H+qNzOV8evuXHfdL7MU7Dy1o7PnfjMTyV"></script>
```

When I try to access the file to modify it I couldn't. I couldn't even find the folder.

[image]

I try to browse the files of templates. Where can I find this js file?

Comment: It is unlikely that this code is to be found directly inside one of your template files. WordPress uses a mechanism to let themes and plugins add JavaScript via a function call, so you probably need to go looking for that.

Comment: You may find that in `footer.php` or `functions.php` . also it may be added by the plugins you installed.